# Is this acceptable OO Design

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

Is this good OO Design assuming you want every inheriting class to be a infinite Thread ? Any better/more elegant way of doing similar thing?

```
public abstract class Base implements Runnable {

protected abstract void doSomething();

public void run() {

    while ( true ) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        doSomething();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want `doSomething` to execute every second, you could move the task to its own `Runnable` and `schedule` it with a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). This way you can reduce the number of threads in your program and save resources.

Comment: scheduleWithFixedDelay, specifically